# Window not closed properly when started from a thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have a problem with my LoadingWindow.
I start a new Window in a new thread in STA mode. I know it's unusual but needed in my case.

The problem is, after closing the window the GC doesnt free the ram and the window remains in the visual live tree:

[image: See image here]

What can I do to avoid this?

My Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_window == null)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(ShowWindow);
        thread.IsBackground = false;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        _window.Dispatcher.Invoke(_window.Close);
        _window = null;
    }
}

private void ShowWindow()
{
    _window = new Window();
    _window.AllowsTransparency = true;
    _window.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(70,0,0,0));
    _window.Height = 1200D;
    _window.Width = 1920D;
    _window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    _window.Left = -1920D;
    _window.Top = 0D;
    _window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

    _window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you trying to open a windows on a different thread at all? It's definitely *not* needed. If you want to perform background processing, do it with a task and update the form as needed. If you don't want the form to be modal, don't open it as modal

Comment: Unfortunately it is necessary, because the main thread is working some ui stuff (we have to do it synchron to the server) and needs 2-3 sec. the loading screen is needed to show the user that the client is doing something.

Comment: No, it's not. Splash screens don't work on separate threads, they are modeless forms that appear on top of other forms. In the past, (ie before .NET 4.0) people used BackgroundWorker. Nowadays they use `async/await` and Tasks. In sync with the server doesn't mean that you need to block the UI thread either. Post your code. The issue that needs fixing is your blocking wait for the server

Comment: What server are you talking about and how do you communicate with it? How do you now it finished processing? SOAP proxies, ADO.NET, WebClient and HttpClient have asynchronous methods, so you don't need to block waiting for a response. Any other communication method can run in the background with `Task.Run`

Comment: The splash or progress screens you see in applications don't work on different threads. They work on the the UI thread itself. The processing though is performed in a background thread or using asynchronous techniques

Comment: Use `Form.Show()`, not `Form.ShowDialog()` to display the form. Use `Form.Show(this)` to ensure the progress screen appears as a child of the parent screen.  Where is the actual processing code? Can you use asynchronous methods, or wrap it all in an `await Task.Run(....);` inside your `Button_Click` event ?

Comment: It's a business application, the server (in java) and a client (c#) communicate with soap WCF. It's a server client architecture, so the client can't run without the server an the ui have to wait for the server answer. the architecture is a bit older and we change the client from winforms to wpf at the moment. so we have an interesting state now. most of the servercalls are sync, but we want to change to async in the near future.

Comment: WCF means you already have access to asynchronous calls. They are either `BeginXXX/EndXXX` or `XXXAsync`. Use them now. What you are trying to do was wrong even with VB6. The proper way to do this with .NET has always been to use the asynchronous methods - Begin/End up to 4.0, XXXAsync since 4.5. You don't have to change anything, the architecture doesn't matter. Your application won't get out of sync if you use the asynchronous methods correctly

Answer (score 0):

The splash screens you see on applications don't work on separate threads. They are modeless forms (opened with Form.Show, not Form.ShowDialog) that still run on the UI thread. Any background work is performed on a background thread. Calls to servers typically don't use a thread at all. Asynchronous methods are used to communicate with web services, databases etc.

WCF service proxies *always* generated asynchronous methods. Up to .NET 4.0, the methods followed the APM patter, ie `BeginMyMethod/EndMyMethod`. Since .NET 4.5.2 the asynchronous methods are task based, ie `Task<SomeResult> MyMethodAsync()`.

Given the new async methods, your code can be as simple as this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using(var progForm =new MyProgressForm())
    {
        progForm.Text="Running";
        progForm.Show(this);
        using(var client = new myServiceClient())
        {
            await client.MyMethodAsync();
        }
        progForm.Close();
}
```

That's it. The UI won't block waiting for `MyMethodAsync` to return. The code after `await` will run only after the server finishes

APM-style methods can be converted to tasks with the [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Converting APM style or event-based interfaces to tasks is discussed in greater detail in [TPL and Traditional .NET Framework Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using `Task.FromAsync` with a proxy that exposes AMP methods, the code could look like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using(var progForm =new MyProgressForm())
    {
        progForm.Text="Running";
        progForm.Show(this);
        using(var client = new myServiceClient())
        {
            await Task.FromAsync(client.BeginMyMethod,client.EndMyMethod,null);
        }
        progForm.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are right, this is the better solution but not possible in my case. The method running while the loading window affects the MainWindow, so I cant run it async. the LoadingWindow isn't a splash, its more a window with an animated circle to show the loading progress.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a great solution... actually it's bad. But in my case not possible to fix in another way. But it's ok for a temporary fix.
To complete this: I changed my code in this way:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_window == null)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(ShowWindow);
        thread.IsBackground = false;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        _window.Dispatcher.Invoke(_window.Close);

        Window w = _window;
        _window = null;
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            w = null;
        }).Start();
    }
}

private Window CreateWindow()
{
    Window w = new Window();
    w.AllowsTransparency = true;
    //w.Content = Some magic Animated Circle...
    w.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(70, 0, 0, 0));
    w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    w.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

    return w;
}

public void ShowWindow()
{
    Thread uiThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        _window = CreateWindow();
        _window.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    uiThread.IsBackground = true;
    uiThread.Start();
}
```

When our application is fully changed wpf I delete this at first :D
Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos for your positiv feedback. In 99% of all cases your right ;)
But in my case I cant execute the methods async... In the future we can but not now.

Answer (score -1):

is it a splashscreen like this one ? [splash on CBR](http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CBR/CBR.Core/Helpers/WPF/Splash/SplashScreenManager.cs)

Comment: the is a nice pice of code, I'll give it a try with Dispatcher :)

Comment: @THeJ don't. It's an *ugly* piece of code. You don't need **any** of these tricks in .NET 4+. Displaying a splassGiven that the earliest supported version is 4.5.2, you don't need this at all. The correct code takes 4 lines